# Split associative Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, split, associative

I have an associative array as below. I need to split it in 2 or more parts  whenever subcategories are more than 5. Is it possible ?
I need javascript code to split this array **dynamically** so that one category should have only 5 subcategories and if there are more than 5 subcategories in a category, it should create one more category with same name with the leftover subcategories.

```
var obj =  [
  {
    "categoryId": "57f22e84c3ed2bd632c061bf",
    "categoryName": "VODKA"
    },
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5a3c3ed2bd632c06225",
        "subCategoryName": "Grey goose"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5fcc3ed2bd632c06227",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut Elyx"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5c2c3ed2bd632c06226",
        "subCategoryName": "Belvedere"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf627c3ed2bd632c06229",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf61fc3ed2bd632c06228",
        "subCategoryName": "Finlandia"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf64cc3ed2bd632c0622a",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut flavoured"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryId": "57f22f18c3ed2bd632c061c4",
    "categoryName": "SCOTCH WHISKY"
    },
    "priority": 2,
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf163c3ed2bd632c06217",
        "subCategoryName": "Blue lable"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf236c3ed2bd632c06218",
        "subCategoryName": "Royal sulte"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf24ac3ed2bd632c06219",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas 18yr"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2bfc3ed2bd632c0621a",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Gold lable"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2f9c3ed2bd632c0621d",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas extra"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2d7c3ed2bd632c0621b",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas 12yr"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2edc3ed2bd632c0621c",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Black lable"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf32ac3ed2bd632c0621e",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Red lable"

      }
    ]
  }]
```

**Expected result should be**

```
var expectedResult = [
  {
    "categoryId": "57f22e84c3ed2bd632c061bf",
    "categoryName": "VODKA"
    },
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5a3c3ed2bd632c06225",
        "subCategoryName": "Grey goose"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5fcc3ed2bd632c06227",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut Elyx"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5c2c3ed2bd632c06226",
        "subCategoryName": "Belvedere"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf627c3ed2bd632c06229",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf61fc3ed2bd632c06228",
        "subCategoryName": "Finlandia"
      },

    ]
  },

 {
    "categoryId": "57f22e84c3ed2bd632c061bf",
    "categoryName": "VODKA"
    },
    "subCategory": [

      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf64cc3ed2bd632c0622a",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut flavoured"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "categoryId": "57f22f18c3ed2bd632c061c4",
    "categoryName": "SCOTCH WHISKY"
    },
    "priority": 2,
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf163c3ed2bd632c06217",
        "subCategoryName": "Blue lable"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf236c3ed2bd632c06218",
        "subCategoryName": "Royal sulte"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf24ac3ed2bd632c06219",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas 18yr"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2bfc3ed2bd632c0621a",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Gold lable"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2f9c3ed2bd632c0621d",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas extra"

      }


    ]
  },

{
    "categoryId": "57f22f18c3ed2bd632c061c4",
    "categoryName": "SCOTCH WHISKY"
    },
    "priority": 2,
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2d7c3ed2bd632c0621b",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas 12yr"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2edc3ed2bd632c0621c",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Black lable"

      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf32ac3ed2bd632c0621e",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Red lable"

      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: how do you want to split it? what is the expected result?

Comment: what should happne with the splitted items?

Comment: Expected result should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a single `category` entry with more than 5 `subcategory` - you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to split them into tow or more elements if needed:

```js
var array=[{"categoryId":"57f22f18c3ed2bd632c061c4","categoryName":"SCOTCH WHISKY","categoryimageURL":{"thumbnail":"link","original":"link"},"priority":2,"subCategory":[{"subCategoryId":"57fdf163c3ed2bd632c06217","subCategoryName":"Blue lable","basePrice":599,"currentPrice":599,"highPrice":599,"lowPrice":599,"currentStock":25,"toggle":0},{"subCategoryId":"57fdf236c3ed2bd632c06218","subCategoryName":"Royal sulte","basePrice":599,"currentPrice":599,"highPrice":599,"lowPrice":599,"currentStock":25,"toggle":0},{"subCategoryId":"57fdf24ac3ed2bd632c06219","subCategoryName":"Chivas 18yr","basePrice":349,"currentPrice":349,"highPrice":349,"lowPrice":349,"currentStock":50,"toggle":0},{"subCategoryId":"57fdf2bfc3ed2bd632c0621a","subCategoryName":"J/W Gold lable","basePrice":299,"currentPrice":299,"highPrice":299,"lowPrice":299,"currentStock":50,"toggle":0},{"subCategoryId":"57fdf2f9c3ed2bd632c0621d","subCategoryName":"Chivas extra","basePrice":299,"currentPrice":299,"highPrice":299,"lowPrice":299,"currentStock":50,"toggle":0},{"subCategoryId":"57fdf2d7c3ed2bd632c0621b","subCategoryName":"Chivas 12yr","basePrice":199,"currentPrice":199,"highPrice":199,"lowPrice":199,"currentStock":125,"toggle":0},{"subCategoryId":"57fdf2edc3ed2bd632c0621c","subCategoryName":"J/W Black lable","basePrice":199,"currentPrice":199,"highPrice":199,"lowPrice":199,"currentStock":125,"toggle":0},{"subCategoryId":"57fdf32ac3ed2bd632c0621e","subCategoryName":"J/W Red lable","basePrice":129,"currentPrice":129,"highPrice":129,"lowPrice":129,"currentStock":125,"toggle":0}]}];

var arrays = [],
  size = 5;
var result = array.reduce(function(prev, curr) {

  // split the subcategories in groups of 5
  arrays = [];
  while (curr.subCategory.length > 0)
    arrays.push(curr.subCategory.splice(0, size));

  // create a new element for each group
  arrays.forEach(function(element) {
    curr.subCategory = element;
    prev.push(Object.assign({}, curr));
  });
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0;max-height: 100%!important;}
```

Comment: @ShifaliGoyal let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this? They all have more than 5 elements, so i'm not sure this is what you want.

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "categoryId": "57f22e84c3ed2bd632c061bf",
    "categoryName": "VODKA",
    "priority": 1,
    "categoryimageURL": {
      "thumbnail": "link",
      "original": "link"
    },
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5a3c3ed2bd632c06225",
        "subCategoryName": "Grey goose",
        "basePrice": 179,
        "currentPrice": 179,
        "highPrice": 179,
        "lowPrice": 179,
        "currentStock": 50,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5fcc3ed2bd632c06227",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut Elyx",
        "basePrice": 179,
        "currentPrice": 179,
        "highPrice": 179,
        "lowPrice": 179,
        "currentStock": 50,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf5c2c3ed2bd632c06226",
        "subCategoryName": "Belvedere",
        "basePrice": 179,
        "currentPrice": 179,
        "highPrice": 179,
        "lowPrice": 179,
        "currentStock": 50,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf627c3ed2bd632c06229",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut",
        "basePrice": 129,
        "currentPrice": 129,
        "highPrice": 129,
        "lowPrice": 129,
        "currentStock": 125,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf61fc3ed2bd632c06228",
        "subCategoryName": "Finlandia",
        "basePrice": 129,
        "currentPrice": 129,
        "highPrice": 129,
        "lowPrice": 129,
        "currentStock": 100,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf64cc3ed2bd632c0622a",
        "subCategoryName": "Absolut flavoured",
        "basePrice": 149,
        "currentPrice": 149,
        "highPrice": 149,
        "lowPrice": 149,
        "currentStock": 50,
        "toggle": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryId": "57f22f18c3ed2bd632c061c4",
    "categoryName": "SCOTCH WHISKY",
    "categoryimageURL": {
      "thumbnail": "link",
      "original": "link"
    },
    "priority": 2,
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf163c3ed2bd632c06217",
        "subCategoryName": "Blue lable",
        "basePrice": 599,
        "currentPrice": 599,
        "highPrice": 599,
        "lowPrice": 599,
        "currentStock": 25,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf236c3ed2bd632c06218",
        "subCategoryName": "Royal sulte",
        "basePrice": 599,
        "currentPrice": 599,
        "highPrice": 599,
        "lowPrice": 599,
        "currentStock": 25,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf24ac3ed2bd632c06219",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas 18yr",
        "basePrice": 349,
        "currentPrice": 349,
        "highPrice": 349,
        "lowPrice": 349,
        "currentStock": 50,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2bfc3ed2bd632c0621a",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Gold lable",
        "basePrice": 299,
        "currentPrice": 299,
        "highPrice": 299,
        "lowPrice": 299,
        "currentStock": 50,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2f9c3ed2bd632c0621d",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas extra",
        "basePrice": 299,
        "currentPrice": 299,
        "highPrice": 299,
        "lowPrice": 299,
        "currentStock": 50,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2d7c3ed2bd632c0621b",
        "subCategoryName": "Chivas 12yr",
        "basePrice": 199,
        "currentPrice": 199,
        "highPrice": 199,
        "lowPrice": 199,
        "currentStock": 125,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf2edc3ed2bd632c0621c",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Black lable",
        "basePrice": 199,
        "currentPrice": 199,
        "highPrice": 199,
        "lowPrice": 199,
        "currentStock": 125,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf32ac3ed2bd632c0621e",
        "subCategoryName": "J/W Red lable",
        "basePrice": 129,
        "currentPrice": 129,
        "highPrice": 129,
        "lowPrice": 129,
        "currentStock": 125,
        "toggle": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryId": "57fdedabc3ed2bd632c06210",
    "categoryName": "BEER",
    "priority": 3,
    "categoryimageURL": {
      "thumbnail": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/barsupply/profileThumb_cy7MXfb.png",
      "original": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/barsupply/profilePic_cy7MXfb.png"
    },
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf942c3ed2bd632c06236",
        "subCategoryName": "Hoegaarden",
        "basePrice": 299,
        "currentPrice": 299,
        "highPrice": 299,
        "lowPrice": 299,
        "currentStock": 100,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf987c3ed2bd632c06237",
        "subCategoryName": "Corona",
        "basePrice": 299,
        "currentPrice": 299,
        "highPrice": 299,
        "lowPrice": 299,
        "currentStock": 100,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf993c3ed2bd632c06238",
        "subCategoryName": "Stella",
        "basePrice": 299,
        "currentPrice": 299,
        "highPrice": 299,
        "lowPrice": 299,
        "currentStock": 50,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf9afc3ed2bd632c06239",
        "subCategoryName": "Carlsberg",
        "basePrice": 99,
        "currentPrice": 99,
        "highPrice": 99,
        "lowPrice": 99,
        "currentStock": 150,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf9b9c3ed2bd632c0623a",
        "subCategoryName": "Tuberg",
        "basePrice": 79,
        "currentPrice": 79,
        "highPrice": 79,
        "lowPrice": 79,
        "currentStock": 125,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf9c5c3ed2bd632c0623b",
        "subCategoryName": "Kingfisher ultra",
        "basePrice": 99,
        "currentPrice": 99,
        "highPrice": 99,
        "lowPrice": 99,
        "currentStock": 125,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdf9cec3ed2bd632c0623c",
        "subCategoryName": "Kingfisher",
        "basePrice": 79,
        "currentPrice": 79,
        "highPrice": 79,
        "lowPrice": 79,
        "currentStock": 150,
        "toggle": 0
      },
      {
        "subCategoryId": "57fdfa22c3ed2bd632c0623d",
        "subCategoryName": "Kotsberg",
        "basePrice": 49,
        "currentPrice": 49,
        "highPrice": 49,
        "lowPrice": 49,
        "currentStock": 125,
        "toggle": 0
      }
    ]
  }];

console.log("All subCategory lengths");
console.log(
  obj.map(function(n){ return n.subCategory.length})
)
console.log("More than 5");
console.log(
  obj.filter(function(n){ return n.subCategory.length > 5})
)
console.log("less than or equal to 5");
console.log(
  obj.filter(function(n){ return n.subCategory.length <= 5})
)
```

Comment: I need javascript code to split this array dynamically so that one category should have only 5 subcategories and if there are more than 5 subcategories in a category, it should create one more element with the leftover subcategories.